# Acceleration time series to velocity conversion using DFTs

Tags: fft, dft, numpy

[image]

I have 1000 Hz time series data for acceleration (512 data points), which I want to convert to velocity. I am trying to use the [omega arithmetic](http://prosig.com/wp-content/uploads/pdf/blogArticles/OmegaArithmetic.pdf) method to achieve this. Following are the steps I am taking:

1. Converting the acceleration-time data to its DFT.
2. Converting the acceleration DFT to velocity DFT using the omega arithmetic formula(dividing each DFT value by i * omega (i.e. 2 * pi * i * freq))
3. Taking the inverse FFT of the velocity DFT to get velocity-time data.

These steps can be seen in the picture above. I am using numpy's FFT functions, and not normalizing the DFT to avoid any confusion.

My question is: Why are the velocity values so low in the velocity-time plot? Am I making any mistake in my steps?

Comment: Have you accounted for the [DFT scaling](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.fft.html)?

Comment: @A_A No...I figured that since taking an ifft of the original unscaled DFT reproduces the original time-domain signal, I should not scale it. Am I wrong in thinking this?